# C++ Program performs better when piped

Tags: c++, performance, time, random, clock

I haven't done any programming in a decade. I wanted to get back into it, so I made this little pointless program as practice. 
The easiest way to describe what it does is with output of my --help codeblock:

./prng_bench --help

```
./prng_bench: usage: ./prng_bench $N $B [$T]

   This program will generate an N digit base(B) random number until
all N digits are the same. 

Once a repeating N digit base(B) number is found, the following statistics are displayed:
  -Decimal value of all N digits.
  -Time & number of tries taken to randomly find.

Optionally, this process is repeated T times. 
   When running multiple repititions, averages for all N digit base(B)
numbers are displayed at the end, as well as total time and total tries.
```

My "problem" is that when the problem is "easy", say a 3 digit base 10 number, and I have it do a large number of passes the "total time" is less when piped to grep. ie:

command ; command |grep took :

```
./prng_bench 3 10 999999 ; ./prng_bench 3 10 999999|grep took

....
Pass# 999999: All 3 base(10) digits =  3 base(10).   Time:    0.00005 secs.   Tries: 23
It took 191.86701 secs & 99947208 tries to find 999999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
An average of 0.00019 secs & 99 tries was needed to find each one. 

It took 159.32355 secs & 99947208 tries to find 999999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
```

If I run the same command many times w/o grep time is always VERY close.
I'm using srand(1234) for now, to test. The code between my calls to clock_gettime() for start and stop do not involve any stream manipulation, which would obviously affect time.  I realize this is an exercise in futility, but I'd like to know why it behaves this way.
Below is heart of the program. Here's a link to the full source on DB if anybody wants to compile and test. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bczggar2pqzp9g1/prng_bench.cpp
clock_gettime() requires -lrt.

```
for (int pass_num=1; pass_num<=passes; pass_num++) {   //Executes $passes # of times.
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &temp_time);  //get time
  start_time = timetodouble(temp_time);                //convert time to double, store as start_time
  for(i=1, tries=0; i!=0; tries++) {    //loops until 'comparison for' fully completes. counts reps as 'tries'.  <------------
    for (i=0; i<Ndigits; i++)      //Move forward through array.                                                              |
      results[i]=(rand()%base);    //assign random num of base to element (digit).                                            |
    /*for (i=0; i<Ndigits; i++)     //---Debug Lines---------------                                                           |
      std::cout<<" "<<results[i];   //---a LOT of output.----------                                                           |
    std::cout << "\n";              //---Comment/decoment to disable/enable.*/   //                                           |
    for (i=Ndigits-1; i>0 && results[i]==results[0]; i--); //Move through array, != element breaks & i!=0, new digits drawn. -|
  }                                                        //If all are equal i will be 0, nested for condition satisfied.  -|
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &temp_time);  //get time
  draw_time = (timetodouble(temp_time) - start_time);  //convert time to dbl, subtract start_time, set draw_time to diff.
  total_time += draw_time;    //add time for this pass to total.
  total_tries += tries;       //add tries for this pass to total.
  /*Formated output for each pass:
    Pass# ---: All -- base(--) digits = -- base(10)   Time:   ----.---- secs.    Tries: ----- (LINE) */
  std::cout<<"Pass# "<<std::setw(width_pass)<<pass_num<<": All "<<Ndigits<<" base("<<base<<") digits = "
           <<std::setw(width_base)<<results[0]<<" base(10).   Time: "<<std::setw(width_time)<<draw_time
           <<" secs.   Tries: "<<tries<<"\n";
}
if(passes==1) return 0;        //No need for totals and averages of 1 pass.
/* It took ----.---- secs & ------ tries to find --- repeating -- digit base(--) numbers. (LINE)
 An average of ---.---- secs & ---- tries was needed to find each one. (LINE)(LINE) */
 std::cout<<"It took "<<total_time<<" secs & "<<total_tries<<" tries to find "
          <<passes<<" repeating "<<Ndigits<<" digit base("<<base<<") numbers.\n"
          <<"An average of "<<total_time/passes<<" secs & "<<total_tries/passes
          <<" tries was needed to find each one. \n\n";
return 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printing to the screen is very slow in comparison to a pipe or running without printing. Piping to grep keeps you from doing it.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but... I'm not doing any stream manipulation between getting start time and stop time for each pass. I made a testing copy and added a std::cout<<"slow down"; between start and stop time checks, that created an appreciable difference.

Comment: Do you have any optimizations turned on? It would be interesting to see if something is getting re-ordered in an unexpected way

Comment: I'm not providing any option for it, so it should be -O0. I've only been using -o output_file & -lrt. Thanks for the idea, I'll try different optimization options to see their effect.

Comment: Optimizations options did not affect delta time between piped and unpiped usage, but they did slightly speed up execution times for both.

Comment: I do have to go ahead and say that you're correct in what's causing the delta time. It is because of printing to the screen, even though I'm not printing between start & stop time. adding std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false); before the loop changed the delta of my original 3 10 999999 example. W/o | grep = 163.796 , w/ |grep = 159.718

Comment: Interesting! You should post your findings in another answer so they're visible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not about printing to the screen; it is about the output being a terminal (tty).

According to [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdout.html):

> When opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the
>   standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and
>   only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive
>   device.

Linux interprets this to make the `FILE *` (i.e. stdio) `stdout` line-buffered when the output is a tty (e.g. your terminal window), and block-buffered otherwise (e.g. your pipe).

The reason `sync_with_stdio` makes a difference is that when it is enabled, the C++ `cout` stream inherits this behavior.  When you set it to `false`, it is no longer bound by that behavior and thus becomes block buffered.

Block buffering is faster because it avoids the overhead of flushing the buffer on every newline.

You can further verify this by piping to `cat` instead of `grep`.  The difference is the pipe itself, not the screen per se.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was using 'screen' and TTY synonymously when that's clearly not appropriate. Your cat example makes a very good point, since it's still all the same output. I did more testing and found the delta is even affected by the TTY I'm using. I was running all my tests over an ssh connection, testing locally has a lower delta between piped and unpiped.

Comment: Do you have any insight as to why writing to the TTY affects my start-stop time result even though I coded it so that writing would be after stop time is determined? Is it just certain liberties the compiler takes with the order that things are executed?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Collin & Nemo. I was certain that because I wasn't calling std::cout between getting start & stop times that it wouldn't have an effect. Not so. I think this is due to optimizations that the compiler performs even with -O0 or 'defaults'.

What I think is happening...? I think that as Collin suggested, the compiler is trying to be clever about when it writes to the TTY. And, as Nemo pointed out, cout inherits the line buffered properties of stdio.

I'm able to reduce the effect, but not eliminate, by using:

```
std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

From my limited reading on this, it should be called before any output operations are done.
Here's source for no_sync version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wugo7hxvu9ao8i3/prng_bench_no_sync.cpp

./no_sync 3 10 999999;./no_sync 3 10 999999|grep took

Compiled with -O0

```
999999: All 3 base(10) digits =  3 base(10)  Time:    0.00004 secs.  Tries: 23
It took 166.30801 secs & 99947208 tries to find 999999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
An average of 0.00017 secs & 99 tries was needed to find each one. 

It took 163.72914 secs & 99947208 tries to find 999999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
```

Complied with -O3

```
999999: All 3 base(10) digits =  3 base(10)  Time:    0.00003 secs.  Tries: 23
It took 143.23234 secs & 99947208 tries to find 999999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
An average of 0.00014 secs & 99 tries was needed to find each one. 

It took 140.36195 secs & 99947208 tries to find 999999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
```

Specifying not to sync with stdio changed my delta between piped and non-piped **from over 30 seconds to less than 3**. See original question for original delta it was ~191 - ~160

To further test I created another version using a struct to store stats about each pass. This method does all output after all passes are complete. I want to emphasize that this is probably a **terrible idea**. I'm allowing a command line argument to determine the size of a dynamically allocated array of structs containing an int, double and unsigned long. I can't even run this version with 999,999 passes. I get a segmentation fault. https://www.dropbox.com/s/785ntsm622q9mwd/prng_bench_struct.cpp

./struct_prng 3 10 99999;./struct_prng 3 10 99999|grep took

```
Pass# 99999: All 3 base(10) digits =  6 base(10)  Time:    0.00025 secs.  Tries: 193
It took 13.10071 secs & 9970298 tries to find 99999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
An average of 0.00013 secs & 99 tries was needed to find each one. 

It took 13.12466 secs & 9970298 tries to find 99999 repeating 3 digit base(10) numbers.
```

What I've learned from this is that you can't count on the order you've coded things being the order they're executed in. In future programs I'll probably implement getopt instead of writing my own parse_args function. This would allow me to surpress extraneous output on high repetition loops, by requiring users to use the -v switch if they want to see it.

I hope the further testing proves useful to anybody wondering about piping and output in loops. All of the results I've posted were obtained on a RasPi. All of the source codes linked are GPL, just because that's the first license I could think of... I really have no self-aggrandizing need for the copyleft provisions of the GPL, I just wanted to be clear that it's free, but without warranty or liability.

Note that all of the sources linked have the call to srand(...) commented out, so all of your pseudo-random results will be exactly the same.